# how to setup nginx having react pwa in one folder and php apis in other?

Tags: php, reactjs, nginx

Disclaimer: I'm not a sys admin :)

I have the following setup:
- react pwa in /var/www/react/build
- php application under /var/www/html
- site url mysite.loc
I want all requests except mysite.loc/fapi/* and mysite.loc/api/* to be handled by react app and (fapi|api)/* by php app.

I am trying with the following nginx config:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name mysite.loc;

        root /var/www/react/build;
        index index.html index.php;

        location ^~ /fapi {
            rewrite ^/fapi/?(.*)$ /html/fapi/$1 last;
        }

        location ^~ /api {
            rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /html/api/$1 last;
        }

        location ^~ /html {
            index index.php;
            root /var/www;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
            }
        }
    }
```

when accessing mysite.loc/fapi/user/get this config returns the following error:
"/var/www/react/build/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory)

what I was expecting was that the nginx would send request to /var/www/html/fapi/index.php. Not ideal but something I can work with.. Ideally I would like the request to go to /var/www/html/index.php, request being /fapi/user/get.

Can you point me into the right direction?
Thanks.

Comment: [This might help](https://nginxconfig.io/).

Comment: You have `/index.php` in your `try_files` statement which is not handled by any of your `location` blocks. You should use: `/html/index.php` or `/fapi/index.php` or `/api/index.php` or a combination of prefixes.

Comment: thank you for your comments.. as this was to difficult for me to achieve I restructured the setup so that now php app stays under build folder of react app